# C# Discover devices with Mono.Zeroconf

Tags: c#, iphone, bonjour

I'm using Mono.Zeroconf ( bonjour ) to discover devices on network, but i have problem to find iphone on local network.I did find printers with _http.tcp but not iphone .So my question is which tcp do i need to use to find phone on network?

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you must define protocol name in your iphone application. For example _TestProtocol.tcp. Than you will be able to see it with Mono.Zeroconf ( bonjour ).